# Limit on Python Celery eta?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, celery-task

Does Celery have a limit on the eta for a task? I want to execute the method `foo` after 12 days, will Celery have  a problem with that? Or do I need configure any Celery settings for such a long eta?

```
next_run = datetime.now() + timedelta(days = 12)
foo.apply_async(args=[], eta = next_run)
```

Comment: Have you tried ??? Well ok, you'll have to be patient <g>

Comment: try it in a vm - you can then tinker with the system time without breaking stuff

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Yeah, have tried.. I guess I will know in 12 days..

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what broker you're using and a few configurations like `visibility_timeout`.

When a task with ETA set is enqueued, it is fetched by a worker asap, instead of at ETA. The worker holds the task until ETA and executes it then. The worker acks the broker when it handles the task; so the broker knows when the task message can be safely deleted.

Some brokers, like Redis and SQS, consider a task lost if it is not acknowledged by a worker for some time, which is called `visibility_timeout`. In such a case, it allows another worker to take the task message.

Back to your case, if you're using Redis, which has a default `visibility_timeout` of 1 hour, delaying a task 12 days may end up executing the task multiple times, like 12 * 24 times, depending on your number of workers.

It may be tempting to increase `visibility_timeout` to more than 12 days. Be aware that it effectively disables the acknowledgment mechanism, which exists for a good reason.

I suggest you use a cron task, which runs at an interval of `visibility_timeout`, to scan for tasks that should soon be executed and enqueue them at their actual ETA.

Refs:

- [visibility_timeout](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html?highlight=visibility%20timeout#id1)
- [acknowledement](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/glossary.html?highlight=visibility%20timeout#term-acknowledged)